# Screencast not working with Google Remote Debugging for Android

Tags: android, adb, lag, google-developers-console

I have my Android tablet LG V-500 running Google Chrome 57.0.2987.132 connected to my Windows laptop running Google Chrome 57.0.2987.133 for remote debugging purposes.

It works almost fine. The problem is, the Screencast feedback on my Laptop doesn't work.

#### This is what happens exactly:

[image: laptopview]

- On my laptop, I click and drag on the screencast panel to scroll up and down. Nothing happens on my laptop screen, but it does trigger scroll smoothly on my tablet.
- On my tablet, I swipe up and down the page. It works fine, but in my laptop screen nothing happens. The screencast isn't syncing.
- If I rotate my tablet from Landscape position to Portrait position or vice-versa, my laptop screen updates with a "screenshot" of the new position, but still kinda bugged, like the screenshot above.

#### Expected results:

- Smooth screencast synced between tablet and notebook.

What should I do?

Comment: I tried another website and it worked much better. Still very laggy, but it updates every few seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

A month later I found out what it was: **The problem was the poor performance of my mobile device.**

If you face this same problem, either buy a faster phone/tablet or try to speed up yours.

-- Edit --

Just tried with a Galaxy S7 Edge and the preview isn't working also! Very laggy.